# How to change system variables of sql on server

Tags: mysql, encoding, character-encoding, server

I need to find file where I can change these variables into utf-8. I can't find them in my.cnf files.

```
collation_connection    latin1_swedish_ci

collation_database  latin1_swedish_ci

collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci

character_set_client    latin1

character_set_connection    latin1

character_set_database  latin1

character_set_results   latin1

character_set_server    latin1
```

Comment: Please be careful tagging. This is obviously mysql and not sql server.

Comment: Configuration files do not need to include all the directives that exist. Those not explicitly set will use default values. So just add the new lines as required. (Said that, I'm almost sure you should be configuring this at application level.)

Comment: When you connect to mysql, use the client's way of establishing the encoding of text.

Answer (score 0):

From mysql doc You can change character_set configuration

> ```
>  [client]
> character-sets-dir=/usr/local/mysql/share/mysql/charsets
>
> [client]
> character-sets-dir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/share/charsets"
> ```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-configuration.html